# Lost on HTML Output Caching in SXA

Tags: sxa, caching, html-caching

I am so lost on what I am doing.. so I am working on an SXA website.  I have done cache tuning and now I am looking at working on the settings for various components.  I literally have no idea what I am doing on this though.  I don't know when to make things cacheable, what parameters to set, what a good strategy is, etc.  The CPU for our website is running at 100% and I feel like it's because we have no cache settings set, but I don't even know if this is the case.  I would really appreciate some help on understanding a basic cache strategy.

Comment: If you can reach out to me on Slack or Twitter I'd be happy to share my recent experiences with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be other reasons why the website is at 100%, sometimes this won't be mitigated by caching. It depends on how your current setup is and what components you have in place, as you need to identify what components can be cached and most important what options to set. To understand the caching options you can take a look at how they are described https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/set-sxa-caching-options.html and [Sitecore Html Caching Strategy](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8872/sitecore-html-caching-strategy).

One other thing to take into consideration is to use the `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx` to verify if the cache limits have been reached. You should take a look at Chapter 4 from the tuning guide https://doc.sitecore.com/legacy-docs/SC71/cms-tuning-guide-sc70-72-a4.pdf

Comment: Great, thank you!